# Binding to arbitrarily deep properties on an object based on rules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

(I'm sorry if my question title isn't very good, I couldn't think of a better one. Feel free to suggest better options.)

I'm trying to create a reusable "property grid" in Angular, where one can bind an object to the grid, but in such a way that presentation of the object can be customized somewhat.

This is what the directive template looks like (the `form-element` isn't important to my question, so I'll leave it out):

```
<div ng-repeat="prop in propertyData({object: propertyObject})">
    <div ng-switch on="prop.type">
        <div ng-switch-when="text">
            <form-element type="text"
                          label-translation-key="{{prop.key}}"
                          label="{{prop.key}}"
                          name="{{prop.key}}"
                          model="propertyObject[prop.key]"
                          focus-events-enabled="false">
            </form-element>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and, the directive code:

```
angular.module("app.shared").directive('propertyGrid', ['$log', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            propertyObject: '=',
            propertyData: '&'
        }
        templateUrl: 'views/propertyGrid.html'
    };
}]);
```

Here's an example usage:

```
<property-grid edit-mode="true"
               property-object="selectedSite"
               property-data="getSitePropertyData(object)">
</property-grid>
```

And the `getSitePropertyData()` function that goes with it:

```
var lastSite;
var lastSitePropertyData;
$scope.getSitePropertyData = function (site) {
    if (site == undefined) return null;

    if (site == lastSite)
        return lastSitePropertyData;

    lastSite = site;
    lastSitePropertyData = [
        {key:"SiteName", value:site.SiteName, editable: true, type:"text"},
        //{key:"Company.CompanyName", value:site.Company.CompanyName, editable: false, type:"text"},
        {key:"Address1", value:site.Address1, editable: true, type:"text"},
        {key:"Address2", value:site.Address2, editable: true, type:"text"},
        {key:"PostalCode", value:site.PostalCode, editable: true, type:"text"},
        {key:"City", value:site.City, editable: true, type:"text"},
        {key:"Country", value:site.Country, editable: true, type:"text"},
        {key:"ContactName", value:site.ContactName, editable: true, type:"text"},
        {key: "ContactEmail", value: site.ContactEmail, editable: true, type:"email"},
        {key: "ContactPhone", value: site.ContactPhone, editable: true, type:"text"},
        {key: "Info", value: site.Info, editable: true, type:"text"}
    ];
    return lastSitePropertyData;
};
```

The reason I'm going through such a "property data" function and not just binding directly to properties on the object is that I need to control the order of the properties, as well as whether they should even be shown to the user at all, and also what kind of property it is (text, email, number, date, etc.) for the sake of presentation.

At first, as you can tell from the `value` property remnant in the `getSitePropertyData()` function, I first tried providing the values directly from this function, but that wouldn't bind to the object, so changes either in the object or form the property grid didn't sync back and forth. Next up, then, was using the `key` idea, which lets me do this: `propertyObject[prop.key]`—which works great for direct properties, but as you can see, I had to comment out the "Company" field, because it's a property of a property, and `propertyObject["a.b"]` doesn't work.

I'm struggling to figure out what to do here. I need the bindings to work, and I need to be able to use arbitrarily deep properties in my bindings. I know this kind of thing is theoretically possible; I've seen it done for instance in [UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/), but such projects have so much code that I would probably spend days finding out how they do it.

Am I getting close, or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to run an arbitrary Angular expression on an object. That is exactly the purpose of `$parse` ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)). This service can well... parse an Angular expression and return a getter and setter. The following example is an oversimplified implementation of your `formElement` directive, demonstrating the use of `$parse`:

```
app.directive('formElement', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      label: '@',
      name: '@',
      rootObj: '=',
      path: '@'
    },
    template:
      '<label>{{ label }}</label>' +
      '<input type="text" ng-model="data.model" />',
    link: function(scope) {
      var getModel = $parse(scope.path);
      var setModel = getModel.assign;
      scope.data = {};
      Object.defineProperty(scope.data, 'model', {
        get: function() {
          return getModel(scope.rootObj);
        },
        set: function(value) {
          setModel(scope.rootObj, value);
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

I have altered slightly the way the directive is used, hopefully without changing the semantics:

```
<form-element type="text"
    label-translation-key="{{prop.key}}"
    label="{{prop.key}}"
    name="{{prop.key}}"
    root-obj="propertyObject"
    path="{{prop.key}}"
    focus-events-enabled="false">
```

Where `root-obj` is the top of the model and `path` is the expression to reach the actual data.

As you can see, `$parse` creates the getter and setter function for the given expression, for any root object. In the `model.data` property, you apply the accessor functions created by `$parse` to the root object. The entire `Object.defineProperty` construct could be replaced by watches, but that would only add overhead to the digest cycle.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zb6cfk6y/

---

By the way, another (more terse and idiomatic) way to write the get/set would be:

```
  Object.defineProperty(scope.data, 'model', {
    get: getModel.bind(null, scope.rootObj),
    set: setModel.bind(null, scope.rootObj)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `lodash` you can use the `_.get` function to achieve this.

You can store `_.get` in the controller of your `property-grid` and then use

```
model="get(propertyObject,prop.key)"
```

in your template. If you need this functionality in multiple places in your application (and not just in `property-grid`) you could write a `filter` for this.

---

The problem with this is that you can't bind your model this way and thus you can't edit the values. You can use the `_.set` function and an object with a getter and a setter to make this work.

```
vm.modelize = function(obj, path) {
    return {
      get value(){return _.get(obj, path)},
      set value(v){_.set(obj, path,v)}
    };
}
```

You can then use the function in the template:

```
<div ng-repeat="prop in propertyData({object: propertyObject})">
  <input type="text"
          ng-model="ctrl.modelize(propertyObject,prop.key).value"
          ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"></input>
</div>
```

For a reduced example see this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/umAZzUrw6MNBrKdeL5Om).

---

If you don't use `lodash` you can use this simplified version of the `_.get` function that I extracted from `lodash`.

```
function getPath(object, path) {
  path = path.split('.')

  var index = 0
  var length = path.length;

  while (object != null && index < length) {
    object = object[path[index++]];
  }
  return (index && index == length) ? object : undefined;
}
```

This function makes sure that you won't get any `Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined` errors. This is useful especially if you have long chains of properties where there might be an undefined value. If you want to be able to use more advanced paths (like `foo.bar[0]`) you have to use the full `_.get` function from `lodash`.

And here is a simplified version of `_.set` also extracted form `lodash`:

```
function setPath(object, path, value) {
    path = path.split(".")

    var index = -1,
        length = path.length,
        lastIndex = length - 1,
        nested = object;

    while (nested != null && ++index < length) {
        var key = path[index]
        if (typeof nested === 'object') {
            var newValue = value;
            if (index != lastIndex) {
                var objValue = nested[key];
                newValue = objValue == null ?
                    ((typeof path[index + 1] === 'number') ? [] : {}) :
                    objValue;
            }


            if (!(hasOwnProperty.call(nested, key) && (nested[key] === value)) ||
                (value === undefined && !(key in nested))) {
                nested[key] = newValue;
            }


        }
        nested = nested[key];
    }
    return object;
}
```

Keep in mind that these extracted functions ignore some edge cases that `lodash` handles. But they should work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

When you creating the lastSitePropertyData you can create the object in this way to not hardcode it

```
 function createObject (){
     for(var key in site){
        lastSitePropertyData.push({key:key, value:site[key], editable: true, type:"text"});  
} }
```

And later use function to get data something like this

```
function getKey(prop){
        if(typeof prop.value === 'object'){
        return prop.value.key;  //can run loop create a  go deep reccursive method - thats upto u 
    }
    else return prop.key;
}
function getValue(prop){
        if(typeof prop === 'object'){
        return prop.value.value;   //have tp run loop get value from deep reccursive method - thats upto u 
    }
    else return prop.value;
}
```

That way can be use in html  `{{getKey(prop)}}`  and `{{getValue(prop}}`
For working demo please have look this link - https://jsfiddle.net/718px9c2/4/

Note: Its just idea for accessing json data in better way, I am not using angular in demo.

Comment: I think your answer misses the two most important points in my question. First, I say "The reason I'm going through such a "property data" function and not just binding directly to properties on the object is that I need to control the order of the properties." Using the for loop won't allow for such control. Second, I say "I first tried providing the values directly from this function, but that wouldn't bind to the object, so changes either in the object or form the property grid didn't sync back and forth." Your solution won't allow for this required two-way binding either.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to do smth like this. 
If you wont to avoid making object.proto dirty (this is always good idea) just move this functionality into the other module.

```
(function () {

    'use strict';
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty('getDeep')) {
        console.error('object prototype already has prop function');
        return false;
    }

    function getDeep(propPath) {
        if (!propPath || typeof propPath === 'function') {
            return this;
        }

        var props = propPath.split('.');

        var result = this;
        props.forEach(function queryProp(propName) {
            result = result[propName];
        });

        return result;
    }

    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'getDeep', {
        value: getDeep,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false
    });


}());
```

Comment: But this won't bind the object to the angular model, right? So you can't edit the values in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar used to show data in grids, those grids may show the same objects yet no the same columns. however I don't handle that in one go.

1. I have a type service where I declare my types and some default configuration
2. I have a grid service which generates the grid definition options according to what I specified.
3. In the controller I instantiate the grid using the grid service, specifying the ordering of the columns and some specific configurations, which override the default ones. The grid service itself generate appropriate configuration for filtering, ordering using the type definition of the fields.